# vb.net "if statement" contains plus sign

Tags: vb.net

I have a piece of code which i am confused about:

```
                If (_campaignIdValue <> "SALESFORCE") And (_campaignIdValue <> "SFNESMORT") And _
                    (_campaignIdValue <> "SFNESTERM") And (_campaignIdValue <> "SFTENNIS") +
                   (_campaignIdValue <> "LEADSINIT") And (_campaignIdValue <> "LEADSEXPIR") And _
                   (_campaignIdValue <> "LEADSRSRCH") Then

                    ' Some code
                End If
```

Why "+" inside the if statement is OK and what does it mean?

Comment: Set [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)(best as default project setting), then you don't get any magic boolean conversions but you have to fix this compiler error.

Comment: AndAlso you might want to use `AndAlso` in place of `And`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)(best as default project setting), then you don't get any magic boolean conversions but you have to fix this compiler error. With `Option Strict Off`(unfortunately default) I think [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce(v=vs.110).aspx) is called which means that anything unequal to zero is treated as `True`. Weird, isn't it?

```
Dim weirdBool As Boolean = 1 - 1 ' evaluates to False with Strict Off '
weirdBool = 1 + 1                ' evaluates to True with Strict Off '
```

with `Option Strict On` you get [this meaningful compiler error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4we5x2t7.aspx):

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to
>   'Boolean'

You should also use `AndAlso` instead of `And` and `OrElse` instead of `Or` since those are short-circuiting operators. Otherwise following throws an unexpected exception:

```
Dim str As String = Nothing
If str IsNot Nothing And str.Length > 0 Then

End If
```

Here both sides are evaluated even if `str IsNot Nothing` is already `False`.